# how to get localized label names on OS X Addressbook?

Tags: ios, macos, addressbook

I'm working with the addressbook framework both in iOS and OS X, now on iOS I used something like this:

```
CFStringRef phoneNumberLocalizedLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel( phoneNumberLabel );
```

however on OS X i'm using this:

```
NSString *emailType = [emails labelAtIndex:i];
```

And I can't seem to find a way to get the localized string, any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I didn't read the documentation thoroughly enough, anyways you can use either `ABLocalizedPropertyOrLabel` and `ABCopyLocalizedPropertyOrLabel` methods, ex:

```
NSString *locLabel1 = ABLocalizedPropertyOrLabel([phoneNumbers labelAtIndex:i]);
```